# How can I calculate top two tags?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my tables's structures:

```
-- users
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Jack   |
| 2  | Peter  |
| 3  | Ali    |
+----+--------+

-- reputations
+----+-------------+---------+-------+------------+------------+
| id | post_id     | user_id | score | reputation | date_time  |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+------------+------------+ -- Suppose:
| 1  | 1           | 1       | 1     | 5          | 1500489844 | -- out of last week
| 2  | 4           | 3       | -1    | -2         | 1500499815 | -- out of last week
| 3  | 2           | 3       | 1     | 5          | 1500584821 |
| 4  | 3           | 1       | 1     | 5          | 1501389166 |
| 5  | 2           | 4       | 1     | 5          | 1501399142 |
| 6  | 2           | 1       | -1    | -2         | 1501399142 |
| 7  | 4           | 1       | 0     | 15         | 1501481186 |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+------------+------------+
-- Note: the last row came from an accepted-answer, that's why its score is 0

-- post_tag
+---------+--------+
| post_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 2      |
| 1       | 4      |
| 2       | 2      |
| 3       | 1      |
| 3       | 4      |
| 4       | 3      |
+---------+--------+

-- tags
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | php    |
| 2  | html   |
| 3  | css    |
| 4  | mysql  |
+----+--------+
```

Now I want to get list of users with their reputations, scores, top two tags in last week. How can I do that?

**Note1:**  *"top tow tags"* means the two tags that the user has earned more repo in them.

**Note2:** Each question has at least 1 tag.

---

Here is **the expected output:**

```
+----+--------+-------+------------+----------+
| id |  name  | score | reputation |   tags   |
+----+--------+-------+------------+----------+
| 1  | Jack   | 0     | 18         | css,php  |
| 3  | Ali    | 1     | 5          | html     |
| 2  | Peter  | 0     | 0          | NULL     |
+----+--------+-------+------------+----------+
-- Note: It's ordered by reputation, score columns
```

---

Here is **what I've tried:**

```
SELECT u.*,
      sum(r.score) as score,
      sum(r.reputation) as reputation
      /* WS_CONCAT(',', t.name) as tags */
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN reputation r ON r.user_id = u.id
/* I need more joins to get tags, I don't know how exactly */
WHERE r.date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY reputation, score
```

As you can see, my query lacks the last column *(tags)*. Honestly, I don't know how I should manage such a thing. Do you know how?

Comment: In TSQL we have to use STUFF() to create comma delimited fields like you want, but it looks like mysql uses GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: I don't understand your obstinacy. You could have had an answer to this (and questions like it) hours or even days ago. But ok. Carry on.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using subqueries? something like:

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,
      sum(r.score) as score,
      sum(r.reputation) as reputation,
      (SELECT group_concat(t.name) FROM post_tag pt INNER JOIN reputations r ON r.post_id = pt.post_id INNER JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.id WHERE r.user_id = u.id ORDER BY sum(r.reputation) DESC LIMIT 2)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN reputation r ON r.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, score, reputation
ORDER BY reputation, score;
```

Comment: Thank you, upvote. Not tested, but it seems like a nightmare ..!

Comment: I think the order by is wrong, shouldn't it be sum(r.reputation)?

Comment: @turo i think you are right, i originally thought by "top tags" he meant top number of usages of a tag, but obviously the question was about top tags based on reputation..

Answer (score -2):

You may tried it .

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*,
  sum(r.score) as score,
  sum(r.reputation) as reputation
  GROUP_CONCAT(',', t.name) as tags 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN reputation r ON r.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN post_tag pt ON(pt.post_id=r.post_id)
LEFT JOIN tags t ON(t.id=pt.tag_id)
WHERE r.date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY u.id , 
ORDER BY reputation, score
```